# Transaction not confirmed

Tags: transactions, verification

It is the first time I use Bitcoin.
I have made an transaction this earlier today. But the receiver informed me that they did not received the transaction on their end. I have looked on Blockchain Explorer. But I do not really understand.

I can see the transaction in question. It states "unconfirmed". Should I just wait, or is there a way to check how many "conformations" the transaction have?

Transaction ID: 83b8fa7226f7c849840c24f4534de5638b3946d612a49953b6919f9ad2ecaa35
Address:3GsUCvwQ2XcUqHjKB5p2nE4txhbdFn9Ttb

If someone can please assist me to verify the status of this transaction.

Thank you.

Comment: The transaction you're commenting on confirmed 6 hours ago.

Comment: Thank you, What can I use as proof to send to the receiver?

Comment: As proof you can use https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/83b8fa7226f7c849840c24f4534de5638b3946d612a49953b6919f9ad2ecaa35 and/or https://live.blockcypher.com/btc/tx/83b8fa7226f7c849840c24f4534de5638b3946d612a49953b6919f9ad2ecaa35/ and/or many other "[blockchain explorers](https://www.google.com/search?q=blockchain+explorer)"

Comment: Thank you all. Let me try.

Comment: Hi All, Sorry to ask again.

Comment: Hi All, Sorry to ask again. I have check the status on Blockchair.  There are 2 entries first: 24 Sept, 2021 07:46 AM UTC - Status: confirmed - But at 24 Sept,2021 09:16 AM UTC - Status: pending conformation. The times are are confusing.  one and half hours after "confirmed", it changes back to "pending"  Could this be a problem?    Thank you in advance.

Comment: @LawrencedeSmidt: I'm not sure I follow. The transaction was included 55 blocks ago. Where do you see the "pending confirmation"? It is a common scammer tactic to claim that transactions were not received, but this one definitely has been for multiple hours.

Comment: I don't see what you see. I see that transaction ID with a time-stamp 0f 0746 UTC and 55 confirmations. 55 confirmations means the recipient has definitely received the money. What blockchair URL shows something at 0916 UTC?

Comment: You may be looking at subsequent transaction 80dfa6ad9b44854d1d18bfb4299df16de931423f2b6b023702451121ef35e644 where the recipient has spent the money you sent them.   ---- to summarise, at 0746 they received your money. At 0916 they spent it.

Comment: Thanx again. So bottom line here: Person stole my money. and there is nothing I can do??